# How to keep request alive between Angular and Web API Core

Tags: c#, angular, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-cloudfront

I have a scenario where request connection timeout exactly after 1 min. due to configuration on AWS CloudFront IdleTime (we can't change that) between Client & Server, due to which lets say if we perform bulk file upload/download and if it take more than 1 min to complete then connection is closed and users are not able to download or upload.

Following is current cloud setup:
Client -> CloudFront -> Load balancer -> Server

Is there any way keep connection alive between Angular request and C# WebAPI until upload or download operation is completed.

What we have tried -

1. On Application or Code level: Request pooling on Angular side and KeepAlive (currently configured to 10 min. but still times out) configuration on C# .Net Core
2. On Cloud Infrastructure level: Changed Ideal timeout on Load balance to more be than 1 min.

Comment: If that's exactly 1 Minute, it should be your Nginx, Apache or some other Proxy server that you are using.

Comment: If you really can't fix that 1 minute timeout (or tell it with a header to not timeout after 1 minute), you could alternatively not do bulk up/downloads, but download in sequence. If for some reason a upload/download takes longer than 1 minute, you can just retry that file and move onto the next one :)?

Comment: Maybe you could think about implementing SignalR for  duplex communication between a server and a client https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr